# Spider highChart - horizontal direction

Tags: highcharts

I'm using spiderChart of highCharts.js.

By default, the spider has vertical direction.

I want my spider to appear at horizontal direction.

For example, when I have only two points and the forum is only simple line, I want to see horizontal line instead of vertical.

Or when I have 6 points and the spider shape is hexagonal, I want the top os the spider to be one of the hexagonal rib, and not one of the vertex.

I attach images here for easy understanding:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the **pointPlacement** properties inside the series object in the official demo will render chart in the horizontal direction.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Allocated Budget',
    data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
    //pointPlacement: 'on'
}, {
    name: 'Actual Spending',
    data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
    //pointPlacement: 'on'
}],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/95av36ms/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointPlacement

Comment: can you please try answer also to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453816/spider-highchart-different-color-for-each-gridline?