# Spider Highchart - different color for each gridline

Tags: highcharts

I use highchart (spider)
I want to give different color for each grid line of y axis.
Is there any elegant way to do that (I mean - without jQuery and complex css selectors)

Please see attached picture.

[image: colorfull yAxis gridline]

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel
can you try answer please?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `renderGridLine` method from the `Tick` prototype:

```
(function(H) {
    var colors = ['#0050d1', '#de0735', '#00e031', '#ffb300', '#c800ff'],
        i = 0;

    H.wrap(H.Tick.prototype, 'renderGridLine', function(proceed) {
        if (!this.axis.isXAxis) {
            this.axis.options.gridLineColor = colors[i];

            if (this.isLast) {
                i = 0;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/45fh27tc/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

---

Or set the color afrer chart initialization in a `load` event:

```
var colors = ['#0050d1', '#de0735', '#00e031', '#ffb300', '#c800ff'];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        ...
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var yAxis = this.yAxis[0];

                yAxis.tickPositions.forEach(function(tPos, i) {
                    yAxis.ticks[tPos].gridLine.attr({
                        stroke: colors[i]
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    },

    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xbLtur48/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: There is no more elegant way to do that?

Comment: Hi @user5260143, I think that is a very elegant solution :) but you can also change the colors in a `load` event: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xbLtur48/

Comment: I will use the solution which you suggest at the comment. Currently I only mark this comment as effective because I want other people to try help me implement it by config. thanks.

Comment: Sure, no problem, but it is not possible to implement it just by options.

Comment: hi,
this expression return empty object to me: yAxis.ticks[tPos]

Comment: Hi @user5260143, Could you share some live demo? In my examples everything seems to work.